# Something like a helper in Phoenix Framework or "ex" file associated with a partial

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I render a shared header in my layout:

```
<%= render(MyApp.SharedView, "header.html") %>
```

In the header I need to calculate some data to create a dictionary and it requires quite a bit of code. I figure I shouldn't put the code into "header.html", instead I should keep in a ".ex" file, but which one? It's not wise to put or plug the same code in each controller. What's the ".ex" file associated with "header.html"? If it's MyApp.SharedView, how exactly should I pass my variable from it to "header.html"?

In Rails it'd be by a helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it's MyApp.SharedView

Yes, it's `MyApp.SharedView`.

> how exactly should I pass my variable from it to "header.html"?

You don't pass variables from `SharedView` to `header.html.eex`, you should create a function in `SharedView` and call that from `header.html.eex` (just like you'd call a helper function from view in Rails), e.g.

```
defmodule MyApp.SharedView do
  ...
  def generate_dictionary(arg) do
    %{a: 1, b: 2}
  end
end
```

Then, in `header.html.eex`:

```
<%= for {k, v} <- generate_dictionary(123) do %>
  <%= k %>: <%= v %>
<% end %>
```